# "admindir must be inside instdir for dpkg to work properly" when trying to install .deb packages not in root folder

Tags: dpkg

For reasons that are out of the scope of this question, I have to install some libraries on a virtual machine that has no internet connection nor GUI. First, I downloaded all the *.deb* packages needed on my host system, then copied on the VM using WinSCP. Finally, using PuTTY, I moved to the folder containing those packages and installed them using

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This works fine since I managed to use some functions and data structures implemented by that library (that for the sake of completeness is `libglib2.0-dev`). Anyway, I need it to be installed not in the root folder but in

```
/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-poky-linux/
```

At this point I tried to execute:

```
sudo dpkg -i --instdir=/opt/corbos-linux/2.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-poky-linux/ *.deb
```

but this error comes up:

```
dpkg (subprocess): admindir must be inside instdir for dpkg to work properly
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead
```

How can this goal be achieved?
Some extra-info on the VM being used:

```
Static hostname: 06e2e468f8c4
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: 07e8a1bebd223fc12a4a73e45d72352a
           Boot ID: ae8230cd752c4e5f8a4772ebf2ae80a1
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```